# How do you get Gem Essence?

Tags: diablo-iii

There are new materials that you can use to convert gems from one type into another using Kanai's Cube. They're called Essence of Ruby, Essence of Topaz, etc.

How do you get these essences to start changing gems?

Comment: Related: [How does “Convert Gems” work in Diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/346812/25404)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Squirt the peddler](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Squirt_the_Peddler) sells them as of patch 2.3.0

You can find her in town, in Act II.

Comment: could you elaborate? Where do you find Squirt the peddler? Does she always have them in stock? Is there any other criteria you need to complete?

Comment: Sorry, on mobile at the moment, will elaborate more when I can test personally

Comment: She always has them in stock, each piece costs 500,000 gold.

Comment: You can find her in the same spot. http://i.imgur.com/agV4J.jpg This picture will show you where she's located.